# How to detect accessibility shortcut button is active in android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, accessibility, accessibilityservice

How to detect accessibility shortcut button is active in android without active accessibility service ?

[image]

Comment: ever figure this out?

Comment: No I could`t figure it